# Qgis standalone Python script results in Qtimer error

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to generate pdf Qgis maps with a Python script but I get this error at the end of the execution, when trying to exit Qgis:

*QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread*

My maps are generated alright the first time I call the function but because of this error I end up with a segmentation fault the second time around.

I have tried many workarounds, looked over every related issue, I still cannot figure out why this happens...

Here is the code:

```
import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFont, QColor
from PyPDF2 import *

def pdf_renderer(format, dpi, title, atlas, params):
    # init Qgis
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(carto_config.qgis_path, True)
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    app.initQgis()

    width = carto_config.formats[format][0]
    height = carto_config.formats[format][1]
    logoSize = params.theme['specs']['logoSize']
    span = width * 0.01
    font = QFont(params.theme['specs']['font'][0], params.theme['specs']['font'][1])

    # setting CRS, layer registry, main layer and database connection
    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(params.main_epsg, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
    mlr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
    mainLayer = params.theme['specs']['ATLAS']
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection(carto_config.psql_host,
                        carto_config.psql_port,
                        carto_config.db_name,
                        carto_config.db_user,
                        carto_config.db_password)

    # loading layer set and setting extent
    layerSet = []
    basemap = QgsRasterLayer(params.osm_path, 'OpenStreetMap')
    if not basemap.isValid():
        print("basemap failed to load")
    basemap.hueSaturationFilter().setGrayscaleMode(2)
    mlr.addMapLayer(basemap)
    for key, val in params.theme['layer_types'].iteritems():
        layer_name = val['code']
        uri.setDataSource("public", layer_name, config.my_geom)
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), val['name'], 'postgres')
        if not layer.isValid():
            print(layer_name + " failed to load !")
        else:
            layer.loadNamedStyle(carto_config.symbo_path + val['style'])
            layer.setCrs(crs)
            layerSet.append(layer.id())
            mlr.addMapLayer(layer)
            extent = layer.extent()
    layerSet.append(basemap.id())

    extent = mlr.mapLayersByName(params.theme['layer_types'][mainLayer]['name'])[0].extent()
    if extent.height() > extent.width():
        width, height = height, width
    extent.scale(1.2)

    # setting map settings
    mapsettings = QgsMapSettings()
    mapsettings.setMapUnits(QGis.Meters)
    mapsettings.setDestinationCrs(crs)
    mapsettings.setCrsTransformEnabled(True)
    mapsettings.setLayers(layerSet)
    mapsettings.setExtent(extent)
    mapsettings.setOutputSize(QSize(width, height))
    mapsettings.setOutputDpi(dpi)

    # setting composition
    composition = QgsComposition(mapsettings)
    composition.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    composition.setPaperSize(width, height)
    composition.setPrintResolution(dpi)

    # setting map composer
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(composition, 0, 0, width, height)
    composerMap.setLayerSet(layerSet)
    composerMap.zoomToExtent(extent)
    composition.addComposerMap(composerMap)

    # setting map legend
    legend = QgsComposerLegend(composition)
    legend.setTitle(u"Légende")
    legend.setTitleAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
    legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(False)
    legend.setFrameEnabled(True)
    legend.setBackgroundEnabled(True)
    legend.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
    legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, font)
    legend.setStyleMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, 2.0)
    legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Group, font)
    legend.setStyleMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Group, 0.0)
    legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, font)
    legend.setStyleMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, 0.0) 
    legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Symbol, font)
    legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, font)
    legend.setComposerMap(composerMap)
    legendSize = legend.paintAndDetermineSize(None)
    legend.setItemPosition(span, height - legendSize.height() - span)
    legend.synchronizeWithModel()
    composition.addItem(legend)

    # setting map scalebar
    scaleBar = QgsComposerScaleBar(composition)
    scaleBar.setStyle('Single Box')
    scaleBar.setFont(font)
    scaleBar.setComposerMap(composerMap) 
    scaleBar.applyDefaultSize()
    scaleBar.setSegmentSizeMode(1)
    scaleBar.setNumSegmentsLeft(0)
    scaleBar.setHeight(1.5)
    scaleBar.adjustBoxSize()
    scaleBar.setItemPosition(width - span, height - span, QgsComposerItem.LowerRight)
    composition.addItem(scaleBar)

    # setting map logo
    logo = QgsComposerPicture(composition)
    logo.setPicturePath(carto_config.logo_path)
    logo.setItemPosition(width - logoSize[0] - span, span, logoSize[0], logoSize[1], QgsComposerItem.UpperLeft)
    composition.addItem(logo)

    # setting map title
    titleLabel = QgsComposerLabel(composition)
    titleLabel.setMarginX(span * 2)
    titleLabel.setMarginY(span * 0.5)
    font.setPointSize(30)
    titleLabel.setFont(font)
    titleLabel.setText(title)
    titleLabel.setFrameEnabled(True)
    titleLabel.setBackgroundEnabled(True)
    titleLabel.adjustSizeToText()
    titleLabel.setItemPosition(span, span, QgsComposerItem.UpperLeft)
    titleLabel.setId("titleLabel")
    composition.addItem(titleLabel)

    # making PDF
    lstPDF = [carto_config.out_path + params.order_name +  "_OVERVIEW.pdf"]
    composition.exportAsPDF(lstPDF[0])
    if atlas:
        composerMap.setAtlasDriven(True)
        composerMap.setAtlasScalingMode(QgsComposerMap.Auto)
        composerMap.setAtlasMargin(0.1)
        atlas = composition.atlasComposition()
        atlas.setEnabled(True)
        atlas.setHideCoverage(False)
        atlas.setCoverageLayer(mlr.mapLayersByName(params.theme['layer_types'][mainLayer]['name'])[0])
    composition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)
        atlas.beginRender()
        for i in range(0, atlas.numFeatures()):
            atlas.prepareForFeature(i)
            spec_att = params.theme['specs']['name_att']
            titleLabel = atlas.composition().getComposerItemById("titleLabel")
            newTitle = title + " - " + spec_att
            titleLabel.setText(newTitle)
            titleLabel.adjustSizeToText()
            name = carto_config.out_path + params.order_name + "_ATLAS_" + str(i + 1) + ".pdf"
            lstPDF.append(name)
            composition.exportAsPDF(name)
        atlas.endRender()

# exiting Qgis
app.exitQgis()
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you add `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` before `app.exitQgis()`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Joseph. If I add it before app.exitQgis() it segfaults right away. If I put it instead of app.exitQgis() I have the same Qtimer error indeed.

Comment: Ah, I think that might be because you put the `QgsApplication` class inside the function (I normally put those three lines of code outside).

Comment: Sadly I tried that one too. I even put them directly in the main but ended up with same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joseph actually had it right in his second comment:

```
# init Qgis
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(carto_config.qgis_path, True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.initQgis()
```

and

```
# exiting Qgis
app.exitQgis()
```

needed to be outside my function. I had tried to put the *init* part in the caller function and the *exit* part in the main but that did not work either. They actually needed to be both in the same place (in my case directly in the main)

Hope this answer can help others !